# Can the weak-* topology in $L^{\infty}$ be characterized by convergence of with respect to simple test functions??

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, weak-topology

Consider the weak-* topology in $L^{\infty}(X,\mu,\mathcal B)$ in which a net $\{f^{\alpha}\}\subseteq L^{\infty}$ converges to $f^*$ if and only if 
$$\int f^{\alpha} g d\mu \to  \int f^{*} g d\mu,$$
for every $g\in L^1(X,\mu,\mathcal B)$.

Since the simple functions are dense in $L^{1}$ is this equivalent to 
$\{f^{\alpha}\}\subseteq L^{\infty}$ converges to $f^*$ if and only if 
$$\int f^{\alpha} g d\mu \to  \int f^{*} g d\mu,$$
for every $g=\mathbb 1\{x\in B\}$ with $B\in \mathcal B$? I understand that this is true if we know that $f^{\alpha}$ is uniformly bounded. Is it true in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No to the question as stated. In fact

> > Suppose $X$ is a Banach space and $V$ is a proper subspace of $X$. There exists a net $(x_\alpha^*)\subset X^*$ such that $x_\alpha^*(x)\to0$ for every $x\in V$ but $(x_\alpha^*)$ is not weak* convergent.

Two proofs, one from the definitions and one using a well known not quite trivial theorem:

Proof 1: Say $z\in X\setminus V$.

If $V$ is finite-dimensional: Hahn-Banach shows there is a sequence $(x_n^*)\subset X^*$ with $x_n^*(x)=0$ for all $x\in V$ but $x_n^*(z)=n$.

If $V$ is infinite-dimensional: Say $(x_\beta)_{\beta\in B}$ is a (Hamel) basis for $V$. For every finite set $F\subset B$ let $V_F$ be the span of $\{z\}\cup(x_\beta)_{\beta\in F}$.

There exists a linear $\Lambda_F:V_F\to\Bbb C$ such that $$\Lambda_F(x_\beta)=0\quad(\beta\in F)$$and $$\Lambda_F(z)=|F|,$$ where $|F|$ is the cardinality of $F$. Hahn-Banach shows there exists $x_F^*\in X^*$ with $$x_F^*|_{V_F}=\Lambda_F$$.

Consider $(x_F)$ as a net in $X^*$, where the $F$ are ordered by inclusion. Then $x_F^*(x)\to0$ for every $x\in  V$, but $x_F^*(z)\to\infty$.

**Detail:** Say $x\in V$. There exists a finite set $F_0$ with $x\in V_{F_0}$. Hence $x_F^*(x)=0$ for every $F$ with $F_0\subset F$; hence $x_F^*(x)\to0$.

Proof 2: If $W$ is a linear spaces of linear functionals on the vector soace $Y$ let $\tau_W$ be the weakest topology on $Y$ making every element of $W$ continuous. Recall:

> > **Theorem** $(Y,\tau_W)^*=W$.

Hence in the setting above we have $$(X^*,\tau_{X})^*\ne(X^*,\tau_V)^*,$$so $$\tau_X\ne\tau_V.$$

**Detail:** Hence $X$-convergence for nets in $X^*$ is not equivalent to $Y$-convergence;  since the first implies the second, it must be that the second does not imply the first.

Comment: Can you explain a little more why this answers the question. Is the idea to take the subspace of functions generated from the indicator functions?

Answer (score 2):

WARNING: This answer only consider **sequences**, not arbitrary nets. For nets, the result fails as David C.Ullrich proves in the other answer.

---

This is a general fact of weak convergence. If $X$ is a Banach space, and $G\subset X$ is dense, a sequence $f_n\in X^\star$ converges weakly to $f\in X^\star$ if and only if **it is uniformly bounded** and 
$$
\langle f_n, g\rangle \to \langle f, g\rangle, \qquad \forall g\in G.$$

Comment: Thanks! do you have a reference for this result?

Comment: It is easy to prove. One direction is the uniform boundedness principle. The other is a standard $3\epsilon$ argument. Feel free to ask if you need more details.

Comment: Oh, one thing. I am reasoning in terms of **sequences**. I don't know if there is any subtlety with nets.

Comment: It's probably not true for nets because a convergent net is not necessarily bounded.

Comment: I haven't the slightest idea, sorry. I have never dealt with nets. Consider asking a separate question on this result and whether it is true for nets.